# How to design a function that takes two Boolean parameters and returns true if either (or both) of the parameters are true?

Tags: boolean, racket

;Boolean b1 b2:

;#true & #true => #true

;#true & #false => #true

;#false & #false => #false

I kind of know how it works, but I don't know how to write it in Racket. I should have two parameters in a function, but how can I write that in Racket. Should it starts like

(define (either-true? b1 b2)

())

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to start the definition. Examples can be turned into tests like `(check-expect (either-true? #true #true) #true)`. [`check-expect` is included in Beginning Student Language; if using `#lang racket` add `(require test-engine/racket-tests)` and `(test)` to run tests.]

Comment: Thank u! Thank u! I know how to run the test now, but I am still confused about what to write in the function( ). Should I use string=? ?

Comment: There are many ways to write the body of the function; the argument and result values are all Booleans: it's not necessary to convert to other types. The definition will have to use some Racket form which chooses between alternatives: [some BSL forms](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html#%28form._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-beginner..rkt%29._cond%29%29). (Note that, for example, `b1` is a _"question-expression"_ )

Comment: @Joezzz See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - even if you don't have privileges to vote, you can mark one answer as "accepted". This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72251184/16981884)
[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72249539/16981884)
show that the body of `either-true?` could be just
`(or b1 b2)` or `(if b1 #t b2)` (or even `(if b2 #t b1)` )

A literal implementation of the "purpose" of `either-true?` could be:

```
(define (either-true? b1 b2) ;; Boolean Boolean -> Boolean
  ;; produce #t if either b1 or b2 is true, otherwise #f
  (cond
    [ b1 #t ]
    [ b2 #t ]
    [else #f ]))
```

In the Racket student languages, conditional forms (`if`, `cond`, `or`, etc) require their
"question-expressions" to be Boolean values (`#t` or `#f`). Other Racket languages use
the [Scheme interpretation of any non-`#f` value as true](https://scheme.com/tspl4/start.html#./start:s106)
in conditional contexts.

So yet another definition, using this interpretation of "truthiness", could be:

```
#lang racket

(define (either-true? b1 b2) ;; Any Any -> Any
  ;; produce #f if both b1 and b2 #f, otherwise a truthy value
  (findf values (list b1 b2)))
```

It's worth noting that, although `(either-true? b1 b2)` looks like `(or b1 b2)`, there
is a significant difference: `or` will not evaluate b2 if b1 is true; `either-true?` always
evaluates both arguments. The difference can be seen by running:

```
#lang racket

(require math/number-theory)

(define (either-true? b1 b2)
  (or b1 b2))

(time (or           (prime? 7) (prime? (next-prime (expt 2 1000)))))
(time (either-true? (prime? 7) (prime? (next-prime (expt 2 1000)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

(define (either-true? b1 b2)
(if b1 #t b2))

also make sure you have both of these check-expects:
(check-expect (either-true? #t #f) #t)
(check-expect (either-true? #f #t) #t)

good luck with fundies 1 lol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your `either-true?` exists already in Racket and is called `or`.

```
(define (either-true? b1 b2) (or b1 b2))
```

Or just do:

```
(define either-true? or)
```

Comment: `(define either-true? or)` won't work (`or` isn't a procedure)